# Xcode 12 archive failed: ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, ipa, xcode12

I've been struggling with this error for 2 weeks & I tried almost all solutions available online. When trying to export adhoc ipa, I get the below error:

> {
> code = 1061;
> description = "ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException: $ /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3
> /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/bitcode-build-tool
> -v -t /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
> -L /var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/ipatool20201005-8057-ws4wo9/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/HelloWorld.app/Frameworks/XYZ.framework
> -L /var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/ipatool20201005-8057-ws4wo9/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/HelloWorld.app/Frameworks
> --sdk /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk
> -o /var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/ipatool20201005-8057-ws4wo9/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld
> --generate-dsym /var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/ipatool20201005-8057-ws4wo9/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld.dSYM
> --strip-swift-symbols /var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/ipatool20201005-8057-ws4wo9/thinned-in/arm64/Payload/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld\nStatus:
> pid 12181 exit 1\nStdout:\n    SDK path:
> /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk\n
> SDK version: 14.0\n    PATH:
> ['/Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin',
> '/Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin']\n    Using:
> /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo\n
> MachoInfo: cd /\n
> ['/Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo',
> '-info',
> '/var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/ipatool20201005-8057-ws4wo9/thinned-in/arm64/Payload/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld']\n
> -= Output =-\n    Non-fat file: /var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/ipatool20201005-8057-ws4wo9/thinned-in/arm64/Payload/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld
> is architecture: arm64\n    Exited with 0\n    \n    Command took 0
> seconds\n    Using:
> /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dwarfdump\n
> GetUUID: cd /\n
> ['/Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dwarfdump',
> '-u',
> '/var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/ipatool20201005-8057-ws4wo9/thinned-in/arm64/Payload/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld']\n
> -= Output =-\n    UUID: E5D8E7AF-7D34-32E1-9337-A84BC4389DFC (arm64) /var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/ipatool20201005-8057-ws4wo9/thinned-in/arm64/Payload/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld\n
> Exited with 0\n    \n    Command took 0 seconds\n    Using:
> /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/segedit\n
> ExtractXAR: cd /\n
> ['/Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/segedit',
> '/var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/ipatool20201005-8057-ws4wo9/thinned-in/arm64/Payload/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld',
> '-extract', 'LLVM', 'bundle',
> '/var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/HelloWorld8zix1rk8/HelloWorld.arm64.xar']\n
> -= Output =-\n    Exited with 0\n    \n    Command took 0 seconds\n    Bitcode bundle version: 1.0\n    Setting platform to: iOS\n    Using:
> /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld\n
> Linker option verification failed for bundle
> /var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/HelloWorld8zix1rk8/HelloWorld.arm64.xar
> (unrecognized arguments: -sectalign DATA llvm_prf_cnts -sectalign DATA
> llvm_prf_data)\n\nStderr:\n\n>\n
> /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:373:in
> `run'\n    /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2808:in` block in CompileOrStripBitcodeInBundle'\n
> /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2747:in
> `each'\n    /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2747:in` CompileOrStripBitcodeInBundle'\n
> /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:3016:in
> `block in ProcessIPA'\n    /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2978:in` each'\n
> /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:2978:in
> `ProcessIPA'\n    /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ipatool:3928:in` '";
> info =             {
> };
> level = ERROR;
> type = exception;
> }
> );
> extractedWatchIPAInputPath = "/var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~UmHmV8/Root";
> }

The interesting part here is the last **Output**:

> -= Output =-\n    Exited with 0\n    \n    Command took 0 seconds\n    Bitcode bundle version: 1.0\n    Setting platform to: iOS\n    Using:
> /Applications/Xcode_new.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld\n
> Linker option verification failed for bundle
> /var/folders/n7/bmb8rpvx1r7g762vv1bm66lm0000gn/T/HelloWorld8zix1rk8/HelloWorld.arm64.xar
> (unrecognized arguments: -sectalign DATA llvm_prf_cnts -sectalign DATA
> llvm_prf_data)

On seeing llvm_prf_cnts & llvm_prf_data, I checked [this apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2432/_index.html) and disabled code coverage and also GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS

**We have Bitcode enabled and the same setup works in Xcode 11.**

Can someone please shed some light on why this might be happening? Any leads would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue

`CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE` was set to `NO` but the CFLAG `-fprofile-instr-generate` was still set. Removing the `-fprofile-instr-generate` worked :)