# Firework ios sdk Archiving error with bicode enabled

Tags: ios, swift, bitcode

i am getting error while trying to Archive my app with Bitcode enable, i am using [Firework](https://github.com/loopsocial/firework_ios_sdk) library which is causing the issue, tried some stackoverflow ideas but didn't help, any ideas?
HERE are some stackoverflow solution i tried already :

[stackoverflow solution: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221973/xcode-12-archive-failed-ipatool-failed-with-an-exception-cmdspecnonzeroexi)

[stackoverflow solution: 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56748389/ipatool-failed-with-an-exception-xcode-10-1)

Here is the error i get in the image:

[image]